# As an individual investor can I buy FSPTX in the UK?

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, index-fund

Not much to add here.

I was just looking at different index funds and [FSPTX](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/summary/316390202) caught my attention with its extraordinary performance.

I was just wondering if it is possible to buy it in the UK as an individual investor, and wouldn't the ongoing fee offset the difference of its performance compared to let's say [PIUSA](https://www.fidelity.co.uk/clients/factsheets/Fidelity-Index-US-Fund-P-Acc/GB00BJS8SH10-GBP/?id=GB00BJS8SH10GBP&idType=isin&marketCode=&idCurrencyId=) which I am currently investing in?

Comment: `it is possible to buy it in the UK as an individual investor` Did you check with your broker ?

Comment: @DumbCoder, of course, I searched my broker website but I couldn't find it, also on the fidelity.com webpage I posted in the question there is a list of brokers who sell that, but it's a list for the USA I assume.